# Unencrypting Berryboot LUKS encrypted SSD

Tags: berryboot, encryption

I am new to the RPi and recently installed an OS on an M.2 SSD (Argon one M.2 case) using Berryboot on an RPi4, and chose to encrypt the entire drive during installation.

If I now want to remove the encryption, what would be the easiest way to go about it?

Could I reformat or flash it, say, using a usb connector, and using either disk utilities to format it on a mac or flash it with another OS on Etcher? Would this remove the encryption fully? Also, could the drive get locked in the process?

I have copies of the data on the drive - so losing data is not an issue.

Thanks.

Comment: If losing data is not an issue, I don't see the problem. Why don't you just start over, and don't enable encryption this time?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I intended to do that but wasn't sure if flashing the encrypted SSD would somehow lock the drive. But taking heart from your comment, I tried and it worked just fine. Happy to accept your comment if you submit as an answer.